# How to change phpsessid in java?

Tags: java, php

I have a java code that submits a multipart form on a site where I need to register. I've tested my script on various scripts and it works when the cookies on the site look like user=username or uid=username and so on, but id does not work when I have something like PHPSESSID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, I can't even change its value. Please help me!

```
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
if(is_cookie){
connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);
            }
            connection.setRequestProperty("USER-AGENT", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset","iso-8859-1,*,utf-8");
            DataOutputStream httpStreamWriter = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream ());
```

Comment: what exactly "does not work"?

Answer (score 0):

The PHPSESSIONID is a ID genetated by PHP at serverside. If you don't have that ID you may not sent any data to that PHP script, because the server 'identifies' the user by that ID.

To answer your question: you cannot change that ID.

Answer (score 0):

### **YES. YOU CAN!**

*but it depends on server configuration

in my case (this is minimal code for educational purpose):

- I create a session with my own PHPSESSID by login with that id
- then i do a multi-part post

  ```
  try {

      String charset = "UTF-8";
      String cookie = "PHPSESSID=aohgsqanei5v2n6su95e0f4vq1";  //custom id

      URLConnection connection;
      InputStream response;

      // Construct the POST data for login change to desired param/value
      String data = "login=" + URLEncoder.encode(".....", charset) +   
              "&password=" + URLEncoder.encode(".....", charset);

      byte[] dataBytes = data.getBytes(charset);

      String _url_login_post = "http://www.domain.com/index.php?action=login";
      connection = new URL(_url_login_post).openConnection();
      connection.setDoOutput(true);
      connection.addRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);

      OutputStream outputStream =
              new BufferedOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
      outputStream.write(dataBytes);
      outputStream.flush();

      response = connection.getInputStream();
      response.read();

      //Find the directory for the SD Card using the API
      //*Don't* hardcode "/sdcard"
      File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
      File binaryFile = new File(sdcard, "404.jpg"); //must exist on sdcard

      String param = "content"; //form data param name 
      String _message = "Message here..."; //form data value
      String delimeter = "------WebKitFormBoundary";
      String delimeter_end = "--";
      String boundary = Long.toHexString(System.currentTimeMillis()); //random
      String CRLF = "\r\n"; // Line separator required by multipart/form-data.

      String _url_mpart_post = "http://www.domain.com/index.php?action=user&mode=";
      connection = new URL(_url_mpart_post).openConnection();

      connection.setDoOutput(true);
      connection.setDoInput(true);
      connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", 
          "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary" + boundary);
      connection.addRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);

      OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream();
      PrintWriter writer = 
              new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output, charset), true);

      // Send normal param.
      writer.append(delimeter + boundary).append(CRLF);
      writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + 
              param + "\"").append(CRLF);
      writer.append(CRLF).append(_message).append(CRLF).flush();

      // Send binary file.
      writer.append(delimeter + boundary).append(CRLF);
      writer.append("Content-Disposition: 
              form-data; name=\"datafile\"; filename=\"" +
              binaryFile.getName() + "\"").append(CRLF);
      writer.append("Content-Type: " 
              URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(binaryFile.getName()))
      .append(CRLF);
      writer.append(CRLF).flush();
      file.copy(binaryFile, output);

      output.flush(); // Important before continuing with writer!
      writer.append(CRLF).flush(); // CRLF indicates end of boundary.

      // End of multipart/form-data.
      writer.append(delimeter + boundary + delimeter_end).append(CRLF).flush();
      writer.close();

      response = connection.getInputStream();
      response.read();

  } catch (Exception e) { }
  ```